# Find PI's main publications

Tags: publications, literature-search, bibliometrics

Nowadays, people in biology make huge collaborations, so of course they're all having loads of publications.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way, on Google Scholar or on other sites, to filter for a PI's publications as last author. That would be really helpful!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found this thread on Github, https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/390 and this software is recommended based on the discussion: https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/390

Comment: Copy-and-paste into Excel and sort (possibly after some reformatting)

Comment: @Monkia That seems to be a website. I'm not sure how that is helpful for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, here it is: https://sourcethemes.com/academic/updates/v4.1.0/

Comment: I don't think there is any universal tool as different cultures & people make use of different scientific CV platforms. For example, not too many Chinese scientists can be tracked using Google scholar nor ResearchGate or even ORCID. Plus, the meaning of authorship position as "PI" is also not universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to search author order in Web of Science, Scopus or GS, directly from their web sites. However, if you get access to a database built on e.g. raw WoS data it is possible (author order is preserved there).

In your case the easiest solution is probably to export all publications where your PI is a co-author from e.g. WoS or Scopus and process the data in excel/R/whatever, to extract the last author name in the author string.

In Excel you can e.g. use this on the author field (AU) from a WoS export to get the last author:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)))
```

This can then be used to filter out the publications with PI as last author, maybe after some more cleaning for e.g. first initial.

Long author strings (which is partially what your question is dealing with, i.e. long author lists) may cause character number overflow though (excel cells can only hold a certain number of characters), so you might want to run e.g. `=RIGHT(A1;100)` on the AU field first to decrease its size, before running the other function to get the last name.

Comment: There is no "AU" field for my WoS export. Only an "Authors" field. And I've tried to apply your formula to it, and it's giving me an error message.

Comment: Exactly what type of file are you exporting? The AU field is found in the tab-delimited export options (the "fullest" export you can get). Select "Save to other file formats" and select a tab delimited format. Then import this file into excel. Depending on your language/region settings Excel might also use a different demiliter in formulas between arguments (mine use ";" instead of ",").

Comment: @Mandel The AU field should contain author names with initials separated by semicolons

Comment: It does, indeed, yet still I am getting an error message when I'm using your formula.

Comment: Weird, I just tried it. Are you using a non-English version. Function names are sometimes translated.

Comment: @Mandel Try the formula now - I missed changing one semicolon (used in my excel) to a comma.

Comment: Great! See additional comment at the end of the answer as well to catch a possible error

Comment: Note that being last author is not a full proof way of identifying a PIs "main papers". Really what you need to look for is whether they are corresponding author,

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Scopus, and know a little bit of python, you can use [pybliometrics](https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

Getting all last-authored publications of someone is as easy as this:

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import ScopusSearch
author = "7103407674"
query = "AU-ID({})".format(author)  # The same you'd use on scopus.com
s = ScopusSearch(query)
last = [p for p in s.results if p.author_ids.endswith(author)]
```

Object `last` contains a list of 30 namedtuples. You can easily turn them into a pandas DataFrame and do whatever you'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could view their profile on ResearchGate? If they have a profile, all of their publications will be grouped there.